# How do i get my html input element to influence my javascript class object value(character name)

Tags: javascript, html, class, input, user-input

I am trying to create a text-based RPG based on the game Bully so the initial characters name can be changed by the user but that's all. All the rest of the values can only be changed through various actions like fighting, exercise etc which there will be buttons for.

So as you can see I created an HTML form input element (this is for the user/player/avatar name).

When you click on the button it should change the first value of the class character object but leave the rest as is.

So here's the form and button:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    <button type="button" onclick="getValue()"> Get Value </button>
</form>
```

This then is the JavaScript class object/constructor/prototype.

```js
function character(name, age, strength, skill, morale, respect, fat, height) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.strength=strength;
    this.skill=skill;
    this.morale=morale;
    this.respect=respect;
    this.fat=fat;
    this.height=height;
};
```

So far so good but this is where I lose traction...

```js
function getValue() {
    var val = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var mainC = new character(val, 14, 20, 10, 0, 10, 10, 1.89);
    document.write(mainC);
};
```

I've also tried putting the form value as is into the object value declaration thing seen above like this:

```js
function getValue() {
    var mainC = new character(  document.getElementById("firstName").value, 14, 20, 10, 0, 10, 10, 1.89);
    document.write(mainC);
};
```

I've also tried using just a click event and adding an event listener. From all these attempts the usual output I get in the console is:

```js
[object Object]
```

Which I believe has got something to do with the parent-child dilemma but it's only a guess and if that's the case I wouldn't know how to solve that issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I've been struggling for months and am close to giving up.

Heres the full game which I'm trying to create just to aid those answering my questions a bit more. So adam would be the here or playable character and wayne would be an enemy or ally depending on consecutive choices made through the buttons being pressed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>
Rule the School
</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1> Rule the School </h1> 
<p id="storyIntro"> </p> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button id="apology">Tell him you're sorry </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="silence()">Put your head down and walk away in silence </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="tellOff()">Tell him to leave you alone </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="shove()">Shove him </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="punch()">Punch him </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="grab()">Grab him </button> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="kick()">Kick him </button> //
<p id="apologyEffect"></p>// 
<script>
function character
(name, age, strength, skill, morale, respect, fat, height)
{
this.name=name;
this.age=age;
this.strength=strength;
this.skill=skill;
this.morale=morale;
this.respect=respect;
this.fat=fat;
this.height=height;
};

// Button responses
document.getElementById("apology").addEventListener("click", function ()
{
document.write("Don't let it happen again");
document.write('<br/>');
mainC.respect = mainC.respect - 10;
document.write("Name: " + mainC.name);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Age: " + mainC.age);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Strength " + mainC.strength);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Skill: " + mainC.skill);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Morale: " + mainC.morale);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Respect: " + mainC.respect);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Fat: " + mainC.fat);
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("Height: " + mainC.height);
});

/* document.getElementById("apologyEffect").innerHTML = currentStats() {};
};
*/

var currentStats = function stats ()
{

}

//Characters
var mainC = new character("Adam", 14, 20, 10, 0, 10, 10, 1.89);
var wayne = new character("Wayne", 14, 45, 35, 55, 20, 5, 1.7);

//Story
document.getElementById("storyIntro").innerHTML =
"Hi my name is " + mainC.name + "and Im came into a fight with: " + wayne.name + ". Do you: "

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also type down what you are expecting the value to be - Are you trying to print something like 
```
value: <What they input as firstName>
name...
skill...
...
```
etc. i.e What is the expected output? 

Right now, you are just printing out a primitive Javascript object which is of course going to print like that.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter. Anyway if i was the one playing the game it would be adam142010010101.89 since it would deliver all the stats given in the mainC variable declaration except the name would be influenced by the user and since I was the user in this case it would be my name that I put inside the text box. Hope this answers your question and thank you for your time and effort. Sorry If I dont label everything correctly

Comment: I added the full game so far just to give you an idea on my objectives. The game works pretty well. The bit that I've made it's just the form issue that gets me and I want to learn about forms since this seems to be a weakness of mine at this stage. Sorry for my redundant verbosity

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to transform a javascript object into a value to be displayed in HTML.
Try to access className.propertyName

Or to display the property names and values:

```
function getValue() {
 var val = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
 var mainC = new character(val, 14, 20, 10, 0, 10, 10, 1.89);
 for (let item in mainC) {
  document.write(item + ': ' + mainC[item])
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far I'm going to add my full game so far just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Hope you'd be able to assist me further. Since the game is playable as is. I'm just trying to improve my knowledge on forms since that is what is mostly required for web design